# How To Save Settings in Qt

Tags: windows, qt, save, settings, restore

I wrote some codes for an application
and I want to save this Settings Like Hide a lineEdit or etc...
and when reopen program last settings will load and when user edit setting
settings that saved updates

what I must do?

note: I Used Qsettings but settings dose not saved!
 if Possible one person Write a Sample Code For me That save current index of a combobox

```
QSettings settings("Mobtakeran Fanavri KabooK","Kabook Physiothrapy");

Secretary::Secretary(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Secretary)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(settings.value("comboBox").toInt());
}
Secretary::~Secretary()
{
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Mobtakeran Fanavri KabooK");
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("WWW.M4RZB4Ni.IR");
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Kabook Physiothrapy");

    delete ui;
}
void Secretary::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    settings.beginGroup("comboBox");
    if(ui->comboBox->currentIndex()==2) {
        ui->pushButton_3->setDisabled(true);
    } else if(ui->comboBox->currentIndex()==1) {
        ui->pushButton_3->hide();
        settings.setValue("comboBox",ui->comboBox->currentIndex());
    } else if(ui->comboBox->currentIndex()==0) {
        if(ui->lineEdit_56->text()==NULL) {
           ui->pushButton_8->setDisabled(true);
        }
    }
    settings.endGroup();
}
```

Comment: You need to use `settings.value` method to load values. You didn't do it. It is not clear, what problem do you have.

Comment: i used this!
see the code!
ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(settings.value("comboBox").toInt());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are saving your settings in `Secretary::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged` you are calling `settings.beginGroup("comboBox")` then you set the value `settings.setValue("comboBox",ui->comboBox->currentIndex())`.

According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#beginGroup), this will set the value of the settings `"comboBox/comboBox"`, meaning that you should read its value using `settings.value("comboBox/comboBox").toInt()`.

Also please note that you are calling `settings.setValue` only in the case where `currentIndex` changes to 2, are you sure you mean to do that? didn't you mean to call it after all your `if/else` blocks?